# Closing form on "blur" -- Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, forms, event-bubbling

So, i'm trying to close a form on blur, e.g. Facebook comments. The issue is, I had a:

```
$(window).click(function(){ $('.comment_form').hide(); });
$('.comment_form').click(function(){ return false; });
```

Which worked fine, however, by adding that `return false`, it cancels out the submit button when clicked when i actually went to make it live.

I thought this would work logically instead:

```
$('*:not(.comment_form,.comment_form *)').click(function(eve)
{
    $('.comment_form').hide();
});
```

But, unfortunatly, it doesn't and i assume it's because when i click on, let's say, `.comment_form` i actually am clicking on `body`, `div`, `div`... etc so it actually hides it multiple times.

My work around was finally

```
$('*').click(function(eve)
{
    if(!$(eve.target).is('.comment_form,.comment_form *'))
    {
        $('.comment_form').hide();
    }
});
```

However, i'm not so sure i like this and this is why im asking. This is going to fire this  click event *every single click*.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this is obvious, but why not use `$('.comment_form input').blur(function() {...})`?

Comment: Because, while this is a form, the comment area is a textarea, and also, i dont want it to close if you miss and click right beside the submit for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is on the right track, but it might be saner to attach the event to `document`, instead of *all elements* (`*`):

```
$(document).click(function(eve) {
    if (!$(eve.target).is('.comment_form, .comment_form *')) {
        $('.comment_form').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm... when i do that though i can no longer click on "comment" it seems to be blocking all clicks... hmm...